# Complexity of calculating matrix with uneven row length

Tags: time-complexity

If a matrix has rows 'r' and columns 'c' then the complexity of printing each matrix position is `O(r * c)`.

However if column length is uneven, example: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` and we need to print each character, would the complexity be

`O(n * m)` - where n is the number of strings and m is length of longest string?

Goal of this question is to verify my complexity. If stack overflow is not the right website, I request alert me with appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: Typically when doing Big O analysis you do it *in the limit*, or basically as the worst case. So the worst case for potentially uneven length columns is that they're all the same length. So it would indeed be generalized to **O(n*m)**, as its time complexity increases as the multiplication between the number of rows and the number of columns. The fact that some rows might have less columns is considered to be irrelevant. Its average performance could be considered to be **O(n*a)**, where *a* is the average number of columns.

Comment: short answer to your question is `YES`. It is `O(n*m)`